# How to change only the tilt in Google Map API

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

My application use Google map API v2, I'd like to change the tilt if the user reaches a zoom level greater than 16

Here is what I've done so far

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    //..    
    mMap = map;
    mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(getCameraChangeListener());
}

public OnCameraChangeListener getCameraChangeListener()
{
    return new OnCameraChangeListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) 
        {
            Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "Zoom: " + position.zoom);
            if(position.zoom > 16){
                // change tilt here
            }
        }
    };
}
```

As you can see I've added a listener to the map object, that trigger whenever position of the camera change, but I don't know how to change only the tilt of the camera

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i've added a `OnCameraChangeListener` to the map object

```
mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(getCameraChangeListener());
```

change the tilt to 60 if the zoom is greater than 15

```
public OnCameraChangeListener getCameraChangeListener()
{
    return new OnCameraChangeListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) 
        {
            int mCameraTilt = (position.zoom < 15) ? 0 : 60;
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(
                    new Builder()
                    .target(position.target)
                    .tilt(mCameraTilt)
                    .zoom(position.zoom)
                    .build()));
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean [tilting the map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views#tilt_viewing_angle)? You can do so by setting the [tilt](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition.html#tilt) field of a `CameraPosition`.

Create a new [CameraUpdate](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdate.html) using `CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition)` where CameraPosition is newly built (in this case with the same parameters as `position`, aside from the tilt). You can then use `moveCamera` to apply the change.